# How to create a circular image using MKAnnotationView

Tags: swift, mapkit, ios8, xcode6, mkannotationview

I overrode MKAnnotationView to display a custom image on a map:

```
override init(annotation: MKAnnotation!, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let img = UIImage(named: "annotation")
        self.image = img
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        self.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        self.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -20)
    }
```

I want to create a **circular** image on the map, but `cornerRadius` not working.

Comment: Try `self.layer.masksToBounds = true`.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with `MKAnnotation`, which is a data model. You want to look into `MKAnnotationView` and related classes for the visual part of your annotation. Check the MapKit docs.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i'm overriding MKAnnotationView, infact the self.image is referred to MKAnnotationView. I need to retrieve a UIImageView from UIImage (of self.image) but i don't know how i can do it

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved with

```
   annotationView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
   annotationView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

but when i use this solution the callout does not appear...

Answer (score -1):

`clipToBounds` will clip the view to match the layer.

```
annotationView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
annotationView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: Perhaps, but your answer is similar to an answer from the OP that is from 2014. Explaining why yours is appropriate in comparison is important to others who are searching for a solution to the same problem as the OP.

Comment: My answer is not similar... that other answer did not work for me. I did not mean to be rude... I'm just saying is self explanatory because the code set the corner radius and the `clipToBounds` will exactly clip the view to match the layer